# How to access Ubuntu from windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed Windows 7 on my system and at the same time I have Ubuntu 12.04. Now I want to access Ubuntu terminal from my Windows, as i am learning Linux now a days. Can any body please tell me how can i access Linux from Windows ?

Comment: are you dual booting or are you running ubuntu within a VM?

Comment: Yes i am currently dual booting.

Comment: This question is off-topic on SO; try askUbuntu next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dual booting there is nothing you can do here. They are separate systems.

I would recommend you look at [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to try out some linux like commands while you are running Windows. You can try out bash scripting, piping etc working with files on your windows drive.

Comment: Thanks a lot oliver, cygwin is great.

Comment: No problem. It's pretty fully featured. It should be at the very least a great learning tool. Have fun!